CreateDate and UpdateDate in Delta Live Table
I'm ingesting a file using DLT with the code below:
@dlt.view(
  name="view_name",
  comment="comments"
)
def vw_DLT():
  return spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles").option("cloudFiles.format", "csv").load(file_location)

dlt.create_streaming_table(
  name="table_name",
  comment="comments"
)

dlt.apply_changes(
  target = "table_name", 
  source = "view_name",
  keys = ["id"], 
  sequence_by = col("Date")
)

and I would like to create 2 new columns: CreateDate and UpdateDate which do not exist in the incoming data. UpdateDate is easy as I can just add the current date to vw_DLT (although it would be nicer if this column didn't update again if no other columns actually changed). But what I'm having difficulty doing is I don't want CreateDate to ever be updated, as that should just contain the information when the data was first ingested and so should never change.
I originally thought to join the source data to the target table, like so:
@dlt.view(
  name="view_name",
  comment="comments"
)
def vw_DLT():
  source =  spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles").option("cloudFiles.format", "csv").load(file_location)
  
  cleansed = spark.table("cleansed_table")
  
  df = sourced.alias("s").join(cleansed.alias("c"), "id", "left").withColumn("CreatedDate", when(col("c.id").isNull(), current_timestamp()).otherwise(col("c.CreatedDate")))
  
  return df

dlt.create_streaming_table(
  name="table_name",
  comment="comments"
)

dlt.apply_changes(
  target = "table_name", 
  source = "view_name",
  keys = ["id"], 
  sequence_by = col("Date")
)

but DLT doesn't support Circular dependencies and so throws me this warning at the point of reading cleansed:
The downstream table is referenced when creating the upstream table or view . Circular dependencies are not supported in a DLT pipeline. Please remove the dependency between.

I also tried using the parameter except_column_list however that's actually just ended up completely removing the CreateDate column

Can you share the code and the table samples you are working with? I'm guessing you are trying some merge/apply changes into operation.

@AnupamChand have updated the question with example code

This may not be the most elaborate way to achieve this but it works. You also need to check the performance for a large table.
You are not allowed circular references i.e. you cannot reference a downstream table in an upstream definition because it has not been created yet.
And apply changes does provide the columns that you need.
So  I've followed a route where I create multiple views (for each of reference) and finally a materialized view. You need a materialized view for the final table because it is not a streaming/append only table.
Also I need to add that this solution works assuming that there are no repetitions of customer id in the file/batch of data that is being processed. If there are repetitions, DLT will need a column to know how to sequence them by and know which is the latest version.
I have used my own schema but the code can easily be extended to any schema.
First define your autoloader step
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import json
from datetime import datetime
import dlt

@dlt.table(name="table1",comment="comments")
def table1_DLT():
  df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles").option("cloudFiles.format", "csv").load("abfss://raw@jridatalakesng.dfs.core.windows.net/cust1/")
  df = df.withColumn("create_date",lit(datetime.now()))
  return df

Now define your first view view1 which gives the customer_ids that occur multiple times i.e. they were already present in the table.
@dlt.view(name="view1",comment="comments")
def view1_view():
  sql = """
  SELECT customer_id 
              FROM
            (
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY create_date DESC) as RowNum, *
                FROM LIVE.table1 
            ) 
            WHERE RowNum > 1
  """
  df = spark.sql(sql)
  return df

Next define a view2 from which you can refer to the first version/record of each customer id to get the original create_dated
@dlt.view(name="view2",comment="comments")
def view2_view():
  sql = """
  SELECT customer_id, create_date
              FROM
            (
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY create_date ASC) as RowNum, *
                FROM LIVE.table1 
            ) 
            WHERE RowNum = 1
  """
  df = spark.sql(sql)
  return df

1 more final view3 which provides details of the latest records that were processed as part of that or any previous batch.
@dlt.view(name="view3",comment="comments")
def view3_view():
  sql = """
  SELECT customer_id, name, mobile_number, create_date
              FROM
            (
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY create_date DESC) as RowNum, *
                FROM LIVE.table1 
            ) 
            WHERE RowNum = 1
  """
  df = spark.sql(sql)
  return df

Finally you can create your materialized view which has a union of repeating customer ids and single customer ids.
@dlt.table(name=f"table2",comment=f"This is a out1 table")
def table2_table():
  sql = """
  SELECT a.customer_id as cust_id, a.name as name, a.mobile_number as mobile_number, a.create_date as create_date, null as update_date FROM LIVE.table1 AS a where a.customer_id NOT in   (SELECT customer_id 
              FROM LIVE.view1) 
  UNION
  SELECT a.customer_id as cust_id, a.name as name, a.mobile_number as mobile_number, b.create_date as create_date, a.create_date as update_date FROM LIVE.view3 AS a INNER JOIN LIVE.view2 as b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id;
  """
  df = spark.sql(sql)
  return df

The first load looks like this.

The proceeding one looks like this.

Try this and let us know if it helps.

Thanks for this @Anupam Chand, haven't had the chance to try the above, but don't think it'd work for me because I wouldn't want to join source to target for performance sake, even if Circular dependencies wasn't an issue.  Basically what I'm looking for is a way for DLT to not update a column, I now seem to have lost the ability to control which columns not to update which I was able to when writing my own merge query

@tommyhmt  The code will definitely work. However, the performance factor needs to be checked and verified and depends on the data volume. As you mentioned, we have lost some control by using APPLY CHANGES. If you can afford to move out of DLT, you can use a standard notebook with workflows and use the MERGE command instead which allows for better control.
